# How to fix an error "this.accountService is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, jhipster

I am new in Angular and JHipster. Please help to solve problem. I didn't change the code there. There is jhipster's default code for login.

Stack trace:

TypeError: this.accountService is undefined
Stack trace:
LoginService.prototype.logout@webpack-internal:///./src/main/webapp/app/core/login/login.service.ts:33:9
NavbarComponent.prototype.logout@webpack-internal:///./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:49:9
View_NavbarComponent_30/<@ng:///NgrkAppModule/NavbarComponent.ngfactory.js:1470:23

core/login/login.service.ts:

```
import { AccountService } from 'app/core/auth/account.service';

--------------------------------------------------

constructor(private accountService: AccountService)

--------------------------------------------------

    login(credentials, callback?) {
        const cb = callback || function() {};

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.authServerProvider.login(credentials).subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.accountService.identity(true).then(account => {
                        resolve(data);
                    });
                    return cb();
                },
                err => {
                    this.logout();
                    reject(err);
                    return cb(err);
                }
            );
        });
    }


    logout() {
        this.authServerProvider.logout().subscribe();
        this.accountService.authenticate(null);
    }
```

core/auth/account.service.ts:

```
export class AccountService {
--------------------------------

    authenticate() {
      some code;
    }

    identity() {
      some code;
    }

--------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading something off of `this` and finding it to be `undefined` is a common problem if `this` is handled poorly.

## Fix

Quick fix is to use [an arrow](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) for `logout`:

```
logout = () => {
```

And probably use it elsewhere (e.g. `login`) as well for future safety.

Comment: thanks to callback. Error occurs when calling logout too

Comment: Cool. I'll try not to narrow and just recommend a direct `logout` fix ;) 

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an reference of this outside Promise and use it instead of this.

```
login(credentials, callback?) {
    let that = this;
    const cb = callback || function() {};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        that.authServerProvider.login(credentials).subscribe(
            data => {
                that.accountService.identity(true).then(account => {
                    resolve(data);
                });
                return cb();
            },
            err => {
                that.logout();
                reject(err);
                return cb(err);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Also add @Injectable() to your AccountService class

```
 @Injectable()
export class AccountService
```

Comment: thanks to callback. I just tried it, not works for me. An error also occurs at logout

Comment: Firefox: that.acccountService is undefined. Same stack trace.
Chrome: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined

Comment: Did you add  @Injectable() to service class?

Comment: did you guys found the solution?